# Indexing on related nodes but not including them in search results

Tags: search

I have two node types, List and Links. Each List has many Links, and is referenced by the entity reference field in the link node. Each Link only has one List.

I'm trying to get the Search API to Index the data in the Link nodes that are associated to the List (such as title and description), but only want List nodes to show up in search results.

For example.... If I have a List called 'My fave types of pasta', and three Link nodes called 'Spaghetti', 'Penne' and 'Fusilli', all of which have an entity reference to the original List node. Now if I were to put 'Spaghetti' into my search I would want the 'My fave types of pasta' List to come up in the search results.

How can I do this?

Also, as a second step, how can I influence the List node title to be higher weighted importance than the Link node title?

I have read what feels like everything I can about the Search API so please forgive me if I've asked a question with an obvious answer!